# Prevent Ajax refresh on search

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

I have this code which permits me to reload the content of a page every few seconds.

```
function()
{
$('#lista').show().load('listaupdate.php').fadeIn("slow");}, 3000);
```

Now, the issue is, i have a search form there, but, how should i prevent refreshing when searching?

Or it can refresh ok, but after the search has been done, and after the results were given.
It's the same issue with pagination, if i go to page 2, then it refreshes and takes me to page 1.

How can i solve this?
Thanks

search form:

```
<form action="listasearch.php" method="post">
<select name="kategoria">
  <option value="dyqani_pergjegjes">Dyqani Përgjegjës</option>    
</select> 
<input type="text" name="search">
 <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Need more code to diagnose.

Comment: WELL, THE listaupdate IS JUST A SQL QUERY WHICH PRINTS OUT SOME DATA!

Comment: WHat do you mean: ` if i go to page 2, then it refreshes and takes me to page 1.`? You show some info where page 1 and 2 are different part of data?

Comment: It's not the content update that is the issue right? The rest of the code is somewhat unclear. By the looks of the code ... is this part of a setInterval? Also what do you mean by 'when searching'? Is the issue that content reloads while the user is typing or some other operation is in progress? If so, is there a way to not refresh the entire content with the search field ...

Comment: Maxim, the issue is, in order to achieve live updates, i just call inside one page another php file. That other php file, has some data in a table and divided in pages, the issue is, since there is a reload each 2-3 seconds, it resets it.

Comment: Damyan, thanks, that's exactly what i mean

Comment: @OziOz well, so if you want to load different part of data to 2 pages you must define ranges per page like: for page 1 run SQL query from 1 to 10, while for page 2 - run SQL query from 11 to 20. It should be 1 ajax into other when 1st ajax set page 'bounds' and inner ajax uses those bounds (per page) to load data itself

Comment: Ok...? So what would happen if you add a clause to `clearInterval()` when you search?

Comment: Heh guess i was a second too late, but same idea in answer below. Still woul dbe great if the updates don't affect your search field at all :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I see this you have two  options:

1. Option 1 : Make the listaupdate.php return just the data and make AJAX call to it, rather than load and the build the markup in the complete handler (the idea is there it no point to reload the whole page, including the search form - just the data that needs updating). See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/
2. Option 2 - cancel updates when search field is being used by the user ( frankly not the better solution, but still). Do something like :

   ```
   var interval = setInterval(function(){
   $('#lista').show().load('listaupdate.php').fadeIn("slow");}, 3000);
   ```

listen for some search-related event (make one of your own if focus deosn't fit the case):

```
$('input[name="search"]').on("focus", function(event){
     interval = clearInterval(interval);
});

// restart it when search is done
$("form").submit( function(event){
         interval = setInterval(function(){
        $('#lista').show().load('listaupdate.php').fadeIn("slow");}, 3000);
  });
```

Comment: Thanks this looks better, i mean i might use the clearinterval better, because it solves a lot of my issues, one question please

How should the search form look like?
based on #searchField?
I'm sorry, i know this is really beginner question!

Comment: I have no idea how your search works, so I assume you have a field (input with id=searchField as an example) for the user to enter something? So I used focus as a start of a search and loosing one as an end. Can't really do better without knowing more :)

Comment: please, just give me a sample of how the search form html should be, based on the code..

Comment: here, ie dited the question.. could you please see it?

Comment: Alright, I've updated as well, changed the restart of the interval after submitting the form, I think that might be better, but in the end it's up to you :)